# Auto-detect tomcat failed start by bash scripts

Tags: java, bash, tomcat, web-applications

I wrote a bash script to auto-deploy a web-application to tomcat container whenever it is triggered. It is pretty straight-forward:

1. Dump the current database for back-up
2. Shutdown the current tomcat process
3. Delete the web-application folder
4. Replace the war file with the new one
5. Start tomcat again

However, now I want to have a fall-back. If there's some problem in start-up process, the database will get restored and the old war file is deployed again.

My problem is that I don't know when a web-application failed to start. One of my implementation is that I will check the size of the logging file of my web application, if after a while it doesn't increase (which means there's nothing get written), then the system should understand that deployment is failed and we should restore the old web-application. However, this is kind of dirty and I'm not sure what will happen if my logging file get rolled right at that time.

Does tomcat has any mechanism to support start-failed detection of a web-application?

Comment: Check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications

Comment: @home: thanks for your interest, but I want to check the success of deployment in the context of the server machine, not through web access. Is there any way to retrieve the same information on the server context, or I really need to do curl to get it?

Comment: AFAIK, the server (OS+hardware) is not aware of the app state as your app is 'just' one part of the JVM instance running Tomcat as well as your app (just one java process). Another approach is to implement some kind of 'probe' servlet in your application. This enables you to test more than just the technical 'is alive' state (e.g. database availability).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) that ships with Tomcat? It gives you an API to easily determine the status of web apps deployed inside it.

Comment: is it http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications ?

Comment: by this way, it seems I will need to curl my domain to get the result? Is there any local way? In my bash script, I have access to all the files on server (including tomcat container). Do we really need to go the curl way?

Comment: Accessing the API and getting tomcat to tell you the status of your app is probably the most robust way. Getting your bash script to check for the existence or state of certain local files is a bit brittle - what happens if the location of a file changes in a subsequent release of tomcat?.